# React Context resets after changing routing using useNavigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

I am having an issue where my react context data resets whenever I change routes using React-Router-DOM v6 as my routing library. I'm very confused because while I understand manually entering a new URL would cause a reload, I am utilizing `useNavigate` to change routes, yet none of my data persists.

I have been at this for a while now but no luck solving the issue.

Here is a breakdown of my code.

First, I created an `AuthProvider`, `AuthContext`, and a `useAuth` hook to handle the global auth context.

```
const authReducer = (state: InitialState, action: Actions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.SET_AUTH:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    case ActionType.REMOVE_AUTH:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {});

  const setAuth = useCallback(
    (data: InitialState) => {
      dispatch({ type: ActionType.SET_AUTH, payload: data });
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  const removeAuth = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionType.REMOVE_AUTH, payload: {} });
  }, [dispatch]);

  return { auth: state, setAuth, removeAuth };
};

const initialAuthContext: UseAuthContext = {
  auth: {},
  setAuth: () => {},
  removeAuth: () => {},
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<UseAuthContext>(initialAuthContext);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthContextChildren) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={useAuth()}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Next, I added the `AuthProvider` to my `App.tsx`.

```
function App() {
  ...
  return (
    <Box>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Router />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </AuthProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Inside my `<Router />` I aded the respective routes for Dashboard and Project.

```
const Router = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      ...
      <Routes>
        ...
        <Route
          path={SectionRoutes.Dashboard} // /dashboard
          element={<Dashboard updateCurrentSection={updateCurrentSection} />}
        />
        <Route
          path={SectionRoutes.Project} // /project
          element={<Project updateCurrentSection={updateCurrentSection} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Inside `<Dashboard />` I added an `accessToken` to my auth context.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  ...

  const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();
  useEffect(() => setAuth({ accessToken: "" }), []); // UPDATING CONTEXT
  console.log(auth);

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

Utilizing my apps SideNav I navigated to `<Project />` using `const navigate = useNavigate()`.

```
<ListItemButton
   onClick={() => navigate(item.path)} // using useNavigate from 'react-router-dom'
   selected={isSelected}
>
```

I expect to see my auth context have a key value pairing for `accessToken: ""` but I get `{}`.

```
const Project = ( => {
  ...

  const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();
  console.log(auth); // CONTEXT IS EMPTY

  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default Project;
```

I tried a multitude of things such as changing how the context was written, seeing if I made an error with the routing, and searching Stack Overflow, but all the answer left me wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `useAuth` hook is managing its own state and callbacks.

Move the logic into the `AuthProvider` component so the single Context value can be provided to all consumers, update the `useAuth` hook to return the context value.

```
const authReducer = (state: InitialState, action: Actions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.SET_AUTH:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    case ActionType.REMOVE_AUTH:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialAuthContext: UseAuthContext = {
  auth: {},
  setAuth: () => {},
  removeAuth: () => {},
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<UseAuthContext>(initialAuthContext);

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthContextChildren) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {});

  const setAuth = useCallback((data: InitialState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionType.SET_AUTH, payload: data });
  }, [dispatch]);

  const removeAuth = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionType.REMOVE_AUTH, payload: {} });
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth: state, setAuth, removeAuth }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually, no wonder the object was empty. I tested out your solution, and it works! thanks so much!